# pandas error when reading file

Tags: pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to jupyter and have been trying to plot using it only last week. I have huge excel sheets .csv format that I want to read and plot. I am doing it by converting the .csv to a .dat format.

My code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap


file1 = 'king2.dat'
file2 = 'iso.dat'

data1 = pd.read_csv(file1, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
data1.columns = ['no_plt', 'Op_RA_plt', 'Op_DE_plt', 'Vmag_plt', 'B- 
V_plt', '(B-V)o_plt', 'no_2_plt', 'FUV_mag_plt','FUV_magerr_plt', 
'(FUV-V)_plt', '(V-I)_plt', '(FUV-I)_plt', 
'no_op_2M','Op_RA_2M','Op_DE_2M','Vmag_2M','(B-V)o_2M', 
'FUV_mag_2M','FUV-V_2M','no_2M','j_m_2M','h_m_2M','k_m_2M','j-h_2M',
'h-k_2M','j-k_2M','(V-I)_2M','(FUV-I)_2M', 
'no_MS','Op_RA_MS','Op_DE_MS','Vmag_MS','(B-V)o_MS',
'FUV_mag_MS','FUV-V_MS','(V-I)_MS','(FUV-I)_MS', 
'no_508','Op_RA_508','Op_DE_508','Vmag_508','(B-V)o_508', 
'FUV_mag_508','FUV-V_508', '(V-I)_508','(FUV-I)_508',  
'no_RG','Op_RA_RG','Op_DE_RG','Vmag_RG','(B-V)o_RG','FUV_mag_RG',
'FUV-V_RG','(V-I)_RG','(FUV-I)_RG','no_RG609','Op_RA_RG609',
'Op_DE_RG609','Vmag_RG609','(B-V)o_RG609','FUV_mag_RG609',
'FUV-V_RG609', '(V-I)_RG609', '(FUV-I)_RG609', 
'no_TF621','Op_RA_TF621','Op_DE_TF621','Vmag_TF621','(B-V)o_TF621',
'FUV_mag_TF621','FUV-V_TF621','(V-I)_TF621','(FUV-I)_TF621', 
'no_onBSS','Op_RA_onBSS','Op_DE_onBSS','Vmag_onBSS','(B-V)o_onBSS', 
'FUV_mag_onBSS','FUV-V_onBSS','(V-I)_onBSs','(FUV-I)_onBSS', 
'no_BSSreg','Op_RA_BSSreg','Op_DE_BSSreg','Vmag_BSSreg',
'(B-V)o_BSSreg','FUV_mag_BSSreg','FUV-V_BSSreg','(V-I)_BSSreg',
'(FUV-I)_BSSreg','no_BSSreg558', 'Op_RA_BSSreg558' , 'Op_DE_BSSreg558','Vmag_BSSreg558','(B-V)o_BSSreg558',
             'FUV_mag_BSSreg558','FUV-V_BSSreg558','(V-I)_BSSreg558','(FUV-I)_BSSreg558','no_aMS','Op_RA_aMS',
             'Op_DE_aMS','Vmag_aMS','(B-V)o_aMS','FUV_mag_aMS','FUV-V_aMS','(V-I)_aMS','(FUV-I)_aMS','no_bMS',
             'Op_RA_bMS','Op_DE_bMS','Vmag_bMS','(B-V)o_bMS','FUV_mag_bMS','FUV-V_bMS','(V-I)_bMS',
             '(FUV-I)_bMS','no _SED','Op_RA _SED','Op_DE _SED','Vmag _SED','(B-V)o _SED','FUV_mag _SED',
             'FUV-V _SED','(V-I)_SED','(FUV-I)_SED']

data2 = pd.read_csv(file1, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
data2.columns =['age','log(Z)','mass','logl','logt','logg',
'FUVCa_14.76','NUVB15_14.76', '(FUV-NUV)14.76','V14.76','B14.76',
'B-V14.76','(FUV-V)14.76','(NUV-V)14.76','GA NUV14.76', 
'(Uf-Gn)14.76','I14.76','(V-I)14.76','(FUV-I)14.76']


def fit_data():
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(8,8))
plt.subplot(111)
plt.scatter(data1['(B-V)o_plt'], data1['Vmag_plt'],  marker='.', color='r', s=5)
plt.scatter(data2['B-V14.76'], data2['V14.76'],  marker='o', color='g', s=6)
plt.xlabel('RA_F',size=20)
plt.ylabel('DEC_F',size=20)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
plt.close()

fit_data()
```

When I had sheets of 4 columns, it would read and plot without any errors. But if I increase the columns, it gives me the error:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fe66f2a2aac9> in <module>()
     13 data1.columns = ['age','FUVCa','NUVB15','(FUV-NUV)','V','B','B-V','(FUV-V)','(NUV-V)','I','(V-I)','(FUV-I)']
     14 
---> 15 data2 = pd.read_csv(file2, delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')
     16 data2.columns = ['no','Op_RA','Op_DE','Vmag','(B-V)o','FUV_mag','(FUV-V)','(V-I)','(FUV-I)', 'no_MS','Op_RA_MS','Op_DE_MS','Vmag_MS','(B-V)o_MS',
     17                'FUV_mag_MS','FUV-V_MS','(V-I)_MS','(FUV-I)_MS','no_508','Op_RA_508','Op_DE_508','Vmag_508',

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    453 
    454     try:
--> 455         data = parser.read(nrows)
    456     finally:
    457         parser.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1067                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1068 
-> 1069         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1070 
   1071         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, rows)
   2261             content = content[1:]
   2262 
-> 2263         alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
   2264         data = self._exclude_implicit_index(alldata)
   2265 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _rows_to_cols(self, content)
   2916                     msg += '. ' + reason
   2917 
-> 2918                 self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)
   2919 
   2920         # see gh-13320

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _alert_malformed(self, msg, row_num)
   2683 
   2684         if self.error_bad_lines:
-> 2685             raise ParserError(msg)
   2686         elif self.warn_bad_lines:
   2687             base = 'Skipping line {row_num}: '.format(row_num=row_num)

ParserError: Expected 30 fields in line 21, saw 45. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

I wasn't able to understand what it means. I don't know where I am going wrong or if I am giving too many columns for it to handle.

Line 20

```
508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.96    0.65    1371    22.925  0.343   3.955           508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955   32  16.111  15.777  15.253  0.334   0.524   0.858    508    12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955 508   12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955
```

Line 21

```
508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.96    0.65    1371    22.925 0.343    3.955           508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.6522.925  3.955   32  16.111  15.777  15.253  0.334   0.524   0.858   508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955   508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955   508 12.76968    58.18559    18.97   0.65    22.925  3.955
```

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the code without modifications? In the code here there are `'` missing, and the column names are not the strings they are suposed to be

Comment: Yes I have copied and pasted as it is. The column names are what I had given in the car format of the file.

Comment: There is an apostrophe missing before FUV_magerr_plt, does adding this solve anything? Or modify the error?

Comment: That apostrophe would probably have given probolems, but it is after pd.read_csv. Could you post line 21 of 'king2.dat'?

Comment: It still is giving me the same error.                                                                           Line 21 is                                                                                           
508 12.76968 58.18559 18.97 0.96 0.65 1371 22.925 0.343 3.955   508 12.76968 58.18559 18.97 0.65 22.925 3.955 32 16.111 15.777 15.253 0.334 0.524 0.858   508 12.76968 58.18559 18.97 0.65 22.925 3.955   508 12.76968 58.18559 18.97 0.65 22.925 3.955                                                                           508 12.76968 58.18559 18.97 0.65 22.925 3.955

Comment: And the lines before? i.e. line 20. It will also be helpful if you can update the question with the whole traceback from the error message

Comment: pandas can load huge files without any problem, that is why I have been asking about lines and stuff like that, because the error is telling you that it was expecting 30 columns and in line 21 it has found 45.

Comment: For instance, the line 20 you posted has 38 columns, and line 21 has 45. This would raise an error, but not this one. Also, this lines are from file1 (which with the code posted with the missing apostrophe is what must be, because there is no way it can reach the line where data2 is defined). However, the traceback error comes from `data2 = pd.read_csv(file2,...` which makes no sense because in the code posted, data2 is defined as `data2 = pd.read_csv(file1,...`

Comment: I want to help, and I think I can solve this problem. However, I cannot do it without your help. I guarantee that this is a `pandas.read_csv()` error, therefore I need you to forget about matplotlib and everything else, and run simply this 2 commands:

Comment: `data1 = pd.read_csv('king2.dat', delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')`

Comment: `data2 = pd.read_csv('iso.dat', delimiter='\s+', header=None, engine='python')`

Comment: Once you have done this. Comment which one raises an error, and check whether the number of columns in the line the error was risen and all the previous one are the same.

Comment: I was able to work around it and arrive the solution. Thank you